# How to create RDD from within Task?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Normally when creating an RDD from a List you can just use the `SparkContext.parallelize` method, but you can not use the spark context from within a Task as it's not serializeable.  I have a need to create an RDD from a list of Strings from within a task.  Is there a way to do this?

I've tried creating a new SparkContext in the task, but it gives me an error about not supporting multiple spark contexts in the same JVM and that I need to set `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true`.  According to the Apache User Group, [that setting however does not yet seem to be supported](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Multiple-SparkContexts-in-same-Driver-JVM-td20037.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am concerned it is not possible and it is hardly a matter of serialization or a support for multiple Spark contexts. A fundamental limitation is a core Spark architecture. Since Spark context is maintained by a driver and tasks are executed on the workers creating a RDD from inside a task would require pushing changes from workers to a driver. I am not saying it is technically impossible but a whole ideas seems to be rather cumbersome.

Creating Spark context from inside tasks looks even worse. First of all it would mean that context is created on the workers, which for all practical purposes don't communicate with each other. Each worker would get its own context which could operate only on a data that is accessible on given worker. Finally preserving worker state is definitely not a part of the contract so any context create inside a task should be simply garbage collected after the task is finished.

If handling the problem using multiple jobs is not an option you can try to use `mapPartitions` like this:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)

val tmp = rdd.mapPartitions(iter => {

  val results = Map(
    "odd" -> scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int],
    "even" -> scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int]
  )

  for(i <- iter) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) results("odd") += i
    else results("even") += i
  }

  Iterator(results)
})

val odd = tmp.flatMap(_("odd"))
val even = tmp.flatMap(_("even"))
```

Comment: That answers my original question well, now a followup question.  I am using JavaSparkContext.wholeTextFiles to read individual files from a directory.  I need each of those files as their own JavaRDD<STring> to feed into spark ml algorithms, but wholeTextFiles returns JavaPairRDD<String, String> of (filename, content) and I want JavaPairRDD<String, JavaRDD<String>>.  I thought it would be super easy to just create a new RDD in a map function, but alas, no...  Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: You cannot have nested RDDs for pretty much the same reason as described above. You could simply train the models iterating over local collection of `<String, JavaRDD<String>>` or iteratively filtering flattened data but using ML can be an overkill if each chunk is relatively small.