# How to create RDD inside map function

Tags: apache-spark

I have RDD of key/value pair and for each key i need to call some function which accept RDD. So I tried RDD.Map and inside map created RDD using sc.parallelize(value) method and send this rdd to my function but as Spark does not support to create RDD within RDD this is not working.

Can you please suggest me any solution for this situation ?

I am looking for solution as suggest in below thread but problem i am having is my keys are not fixed and i can have any number of keys.
[How to create RDD from within Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011373/how-to-create-rdd-from-within-task)

Thanks

Comment: There is no generic solution. RDD cannot be called from a map. If you provide some code with your logic it might be possible to suggest a suitable change.

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you depending on an `RDD` inside your own function logic?

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to achieve with Spark? Could you please describe your use case (not how you try to use Spark for it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't create RDD inside RDD.

Depends on the size of your data, there could be two solutions:

1) If there are many keys and each key has not too much values. Turn the function which accepts RDD to a function which accepts Iterable. Then you can do some thing like

```
// rdd: RDD[(keyType, valueType)]
rdd.groupByKey()
  .map { case (key, values) =>
    func(values)
  }
```

2) If there are few keys and each key has many values. Then you should not do a group as it would collect all values for a key to an executor, which may cause OutOfMemory. Instead, run a job for each key like

```
rdd.keys.distinct().collect()
  .foreach { key =>
    func(rdd.filter(_._1 == key))         
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound quite right. If the function needs to process the key value pair, it should receive the pair as the parameter, not RDD.

But if you really want to send the RDD as a parameter, instead of inside the chain operation, you may create a reference after preprocessing and send that reference to the method.